# What best way to document the requirements?

Tags: requirements

We have 3 different systems which exchanges data on a regular basis. There are

- Some standard mappings between fields (Ex: field Category= A or B depending on input).
- Indirect mappings between fields. (Ex: field Prio= A or B depending on input along severity)
- Filling Mandatory  fields (Ex: Summary)
- Standard Workflows.
- Indirect workflows.
- Some specific functional and non-functional requirements.

Writing as text is too much as it has only long textual data. I am wondering how we could write such requirements? User stories?

Thanks

Comment: Technically, none of these are requirements, except maybe the last bullet.  They are *specifications.*

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. How can these specifications be written down? Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.bradapp.com/docs/sdd.html

Comment: In a requirements document, how many references/examples/etc of long text data would you need to include? Otherwise, I don't see how the contents of a data type makes a difference.

Comment: Questions that ask for the *best* or *right* way are often hard to answer. They are easier to answer in the context of some specific problem or challenge you are experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

For standard and indirect workflow, you could represent the business requirement with [BPMN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation). It is a graphical notation which is designed for exactly that. It became ISO 19510 international standard: so there is some consensus about it. In addition it is well suited for orchestration of processes running on different systems.

For system requirement, that do not focus on  intersystem coordination, you could consider use cases. But uml use case or [use case 2.0](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook) are more to document high level goals and observable behaviors in relation with system actors. These are not appropriate for field level requirements and non functional requirements.

You could consider Cockburn like narrative use cases instead or in complement of uml. But these are again more appropriate for interactions and business requirements.

The kind of very technical requirements seem to be more about data specification and mapping than objective requirements. If textual description is too long, you could opt for a data model or a class diagram. Uml let you express constraints in natural language that could help you to describe the mapping. But keep in mind that this kind of expression is not understandable for the average user. So it may be more effective to express these kind of data rules in form of a readable bullet list.